# Getting error "undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.navigate')" after firebase auth - react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

Hi I'm getting the error undefined is not an object(evaluating 'navigation.navigate') after I'm submitting the form. I searched many google/stackoverflow answers but none of them helped me.

I'm not sure if this is cause by firebase or actual prop navigation. Any insights on this ???

Please see the code below:

```js
// parent component

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from '../components/LoginForm';

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainWrapper}>
            <Image style={styles.logo} title="Logo" source={require('../assets/box.png')}/>
            <LoginForm/>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
        width: 150,
        height: 150,
        marginTop: 55
    },
    mainWrapper: {
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center"
    }
});

export default Login;






// login form component

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import { firebaseConfig } from '../config';

if(!firebase.apps.length){
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

const auth = firebase.auth();

const LoginForm = ({navigation}) => {

    const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const signIn = async() => {
        try {
            let response = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
            if(response.user){
                Alert.alert('logged in' + response.user.email);
                navigation.navigate('Driver');
            }
        }catch(e){
            Alert.alert(e.message);
        }
    };

    return (
        <View style={styles.formView}>
            <TextInput
            value={email}
            placeholder="Email" 
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={userEmail => setEmail(userEmail)}
            autoCapitalize='none'
            keyboardType='email-address'
            autoCorrect={false}
            />

            <TextInput 
            value={password}
            placeholder="Password" 
            secureTextEntry={true} 
            style={styles.input}
            onChangeText={userPassword => setPassword(userPassword)}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.submitBtn} title="Login" onPress={() => signIn()}>
                <Text style={styles.appButtonText}>Login</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    formView: {
        marginTop: 45,
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
    },
    input: {
        marginTop: 20,
        width: 300,
        height: 40,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        borderRadius: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    submitBtn: {
        backgroundColor: "#FFE17D",
        color: "#E6646E",
        fontWeight: "bold",
        width: 150,
        height: 40,
        marginTop: 20,
        borderColor: "#E6646E",
        borderRadius: 5,
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        borderWidth: 1,
    },
    appButtonText: {
      fontSize: 18,
      color: "#E6646E",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      alignSelf: "center",
      textTransform: "uppercase"
    }
});
```

Comment: Please share the parent component as well, so we dont play guess as to what props.navigation is

Comment: Is the Login component part of a stack ? there is no code related to navigation here and you are not passing a navigation prop to LoginForm as well

Comment: Login component is not part of the stack

Comment: If its not part of the stack you should use the ref 
Check the api https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the stack screens have access to the props navigation. You can try sending navigation to LoginForm but that works only if Login is a Stack Screen.

```
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainWrapper}>
            <Image style={styles.logo} title="Logo" source={require('../assets/box.png')}/>
            <LoginForm navigation={navigation}/>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Or you can have a look in the useNavigation hook